# Lock a variable stored in req.session, or make a huge global var?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, locking

I am writing a game in node.js, basically, you send units in mission and wait for them to return. Of course, you can t send the same unit in two missions, and can t send two set of units on the same mission.

Every unit owned by the player is stored in req.session (Express session), so before starting the mission, I check if they are in use, if so, abort the mission, if free, mark them as in use and continue.

That's where the problem arise, I don't know if req.session is shared or if every route get its own copy of it, and can t reliably mark them as in use.

I've tried semaphore (npm module 'locks'), but the result is the same.

Here is the (cutted to the relevant part) logs:

```
E:\Documents\GIT\_>node app.js
2015/6/15 23:51:55:582  /start          get
2015/6/15 23:51:55:582  /start          parameters:
        squad: 0,1
        mission: 1
2015/6/15 23:51:55:612  start_miss      squad locked
2015/6/15 23:51:55:613  start_miss      Waiting

2015/6/15 23:51:56:73   /start          parameters:
        squad: 0,1
        mission: 1
2015/6/15 23:51:56:75   start_miss      squad locked
2015/6/15 23:51:56:76   start_miss      Waiting

2015/6/15 23:51:56:625  end_missio      End mission
2015/6/15 23:51:57:88   end_missio      End mission
```

And here is my "lock_squad" code:

```
function lock_unit(req, squad, callback, i) {
    setImmediate(function () {
        if(!i) {i = 0;}
        log(log_level['DEBUG'], 'lock_unit', 'start ' + (i + 1) + ' / ' + squad.length);
        if(i < squad.length) {
            search_id(req.session.units, squad[i], function (id) {
                req.session.units[id].deployed = true;
                lock_unit(req, squad, callback, i + 1);
            });
        } else {
            callback();
        }
    });
}
```

Basically, the question is:

How can I lock a variable (element in a array stored in session) so that the object can't be used by another, or the same route, until the request is processed?

EDIT:

It seems that req is a copy, so I should change my implementation to give every sessions a id, and use that id to link to a global variable containing every units of every sessions, and lock this. It seems like a bad idea to me, because either the node process will eat a awful lot of memory, either I ll need to make a "garbage collector" manually, whith every trap that incur.

Anybody with a better idea?

Comment: Related, but using redis (I m using mongoDB): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11165319/how-can-i-avoid-race-conditions-in-node-js-when-im-manipulating-the-session-via & http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11420982/connect-redis-how-to-protect-the-session-object-against-race-condition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Express save the session on `res.end()`, which in my case is sent long after the second request is seen.

Which mean I still need to lock the session (a la redis-lock, will need to find the mongoDB equivalent), and end the res before starting computing the battle.